# How to create a function in VBA to return column names matching a certain criteria for each record in a recordset?

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I have a table that contains a response to a survey. e.g.,
TableA:

```
CompanyID   Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5
CompanyA    I   I   N   N   I
CompanyB    I   I   I   I   I
CompanyC    I   I   N   N   N
```

I am using MS-Access 2016. I want to create a VBA function that would allow me to go through each record in this table and return the field.name where the response to the question is an "N" that is separated by a comma (,).

Please keep in mind am by no means an expert, nor had any formal training. To be honest, I learn most of my VBA through this forum. Thank you all who has provided input to this community.

So far I am able to get VBA to loop through each record but I am running into several problems, please see code below:

```
Public Function NResponses(strTable As String)

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset      
    Dim fld As DAO.Field          
    Dim strOut As String            
    Dim lngLen As Long                     
    Dim strSeperator As String      

NResponses = Null

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("TableA")
strSeperator = ", "

Do While Not rs.EOF
    With rs
        For Each fld In .Fields
            If fld.Value = "N" Then
                strOut = strOut & fld.Name & strSeperator
            End If
        Next fld
        rs.MoveNext
    End With
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

'Clean Output - remove last comma from strOut
lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeperator)
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        MissingControls = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    'Clean up
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "NResponses()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

This returns the below:

```
CompanyID   Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  NResponses
CompanyA    I   I   N   N   I   Q1, Q3, Q4, Q5
CompanyB    I   I   I   I   I   Q1, Q3, Q4, Q5
CompanyC    N   I   I   N   N   Q1, Q3, Q4, Q5
```

But, my desired end result is this:

```
CompanyID   Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  NResponses
CompanyA    I   I   N   N   I   Q3, Q4
CompanyB    I   I   I   I   I   
CompanyC    N   I   I   N   N   Q1, Q4, Q5
```

You're help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You loop through the whole table, but you never reset `strOut`. So it just keeps accumulating values. If you want to use the function in a query, as suggested by your desired result, this approach is not going to work at all. You need to go full VBA or full query.

Comment: @Andre - it makes sense that because I never reset the strOut would be the reason for it accumulating values.  I've tried several ways to make that change, but still unable to get the desired result.  Since you say that this will not work - any more guidance on how I should approach this through full VBA or Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an SQL solution using a special VBA function, Allen Browne's [`ConcatRelated`](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) to be called inside SQL query. Copy and save the function inside an Access standard module.

First, reshape your wide table into long format with a union query.

```sql
SELECT Surveys.CompanyID, 'Q1' As Question, Surveys.Q1 As Response
FROM Surveys

UNION ALL
SELECT Surveys.CompanyID, 'Q2' As Question, Surveys.Q2 As Response
FROM Surveys

UNION ALL
SELECT Surveys.CompanyID, 'Q3' As Question, Surveys.Q3 As Response
FROM Surveys

UNION ALL
SELECT Surveys.CompanyID, 'Q4' As Question, Surveys.Q4 As Response
FROM Surveys

UNION ALL
SELECT Surveys.CompanyID, 'Q5' As Question, Surveys.Q5 As Response
FROM Surveys
```

Second, run conditional aggregation with `ConcatRelated()` to reshape long back to wide

```sql
SELECT s.CompanyID, 
       MAX(IIF(s.Question = 'Q1', s.Response)) As Q1,
       MAX(IIF(s.Question = 'Q2', s.Response)) As Q2,
       MAX(IIF(s.Question = 'Q3', s.Response)) As Q3,
       MAX(IIF(s.Question = 'Q4', s.Response)) As Q4,
       MAX(IIF(s.Question = 'Q5', s.Response)) As Q5,
       ConcatRelated("Question", "SurveysUnionQ", 
                     "CompanyID = '" & s.CompanyID & "' AND Response = 'N'") AS NResponses
FROM SurveysLongTableOrUnionQuery s
GROUP BY s.CompanyID
```

[image: SQL Query Output]

---

### Dynamic Solution

If there are many questions that above is not feasible, build a dynamic union query through looped code. Alternatively, create a table and run `INSERT...SELECT` iteratively by each *CompanyID* and *Question* as shown below:

```vb
Public Sub BuildSurveyLongTable()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
    Dim db As DAO.Database, tblDef As TableDef

    Set db = CurrentDb
    ' MAKE-TABLE QUERY (RUN ONLY ONCE, COMMENT OUT THEREAFTER)
'    db.Execute "SELECT TOP 1 Surveys.CompanyID, 'Q1' As Question, Surveys.Q1 As Response INTO SurveysLong FROM Surveys"
    db.Execute "DELETE FROM SurveysLong"

    Set tblDef = db.TableDefs("Surveys")

    For i = 2 To tblDef.Fields.Count - 1
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO SurveysLong (CompanyID, Question, Response)" _
                     & " SELECT Surveys.CompanyID, '" & tblDef.Fields(i).name & "' As Question," _
                     & "        Surveys.[" & tblDef.Fields(i).name & "] As Response" _
                     & " FROM Surveys"
    Next i

    MsgBox "Successfully completed!", vbInformation

Exit_Handler:
    Set tblDef = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUN-TIME ERROR"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

As above, below is a dynamic query for the conditional aggregation:

```vb
Public Sub BuildSurveyQuery()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database, tblDef As TableDef, qdef As QueryDef

    strSQL = "SELECT s.CompanyID, "

    ' ITERATIVELY ADD CONDITIONAL AGGREGATION LINES
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tblDef = db.TableDefs("Surveys")

    For i = 2 To tblDef.Fields.Count - 1
        strSQL = strSQL & "MAX(IIF(s.Question = '" & tblDef.Fields(i).name & "', s.Response)) As [" & tblDef.Fields(i).name & "], "
    Next i

    ' REMOVE LAST COMMA
    strSQL = Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 1)

    strSQL = strSQL & " ConcatRelated(""Question"", ""SurveysUnionQ""," _
                    & "              ""CompanyID = '"" & s.CompanyID & ""' AND Response = 'N'"") AS NResponses" _
                    & " FROM SurveysLong s" _
                    & " GROUP BY s.CompanyID"

    ' UPDATE SQL IN QUERY OBJECT AND RELEASE TO SAVE
    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("SurveysWideConcatQ")
    qdef.SQL = strSQL
    Set qdef = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully completed!", vbInformation

Exit_Handler:
    Set tblDef = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUN-TIME ERROR"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

---

### Pivot Query

In fact, an alternative to the conditional aggregation is Access's exclusive [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) which can accommodate up to 253 questions (255 max number of columns) also including the `ConcatRelated`. Do note: *NResponses* will appear to the left of question columns and not at the end to far right.

```sql
TRANSFORM Max(s.Response) AS MaxResponse
SELECT s.CompanyID, 
       ConcatRelated("Question", "SurveysLong",    
                     "CompanyID = '" & s.CompanyID & "' AND Response = 'N'") AS NResponses
FROM SurveysLong s
GROUP BY s.CompanyID
PIVOT s.Question
```

Comment: This looks like a very interesting solution, but like you've mentioned - there are about 200 questions and thousands of companies.  If I would to follow your advice and  "Alternatively, create a table and run "Insert....Select" iteratively in a loop by each companyID and Question... how would I do that. Don't really understand what you mean. A link to a resource would help.

Comment: See update with subroutines to create table and iteratively insert rows AND update SQL of query for conditional aggregates for up to 200 questions. I even add a crosstab query.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide these examples.  I think I understand what you're trying to convey and will probably need to do some editing to the Dynamic Queries as the field names in my actual table is not sequential - really no specific order.  I will provide updates as I work through your examples.

Comment: See update now iterating through table columns to build temp table and conditional agg query (and once again the latter query can be replaced with crosstab query).

Comment: This is great stuff.  I ended up using the Dynamic solution with the pivot query you've provided and everything works like a charm.  I will note that due to the table size that I'm working with, the performance is pretty bad (+300K records and takes the pivot query 15 mins to process).  Overall the solution works as intended and I got the desired results.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked. Consider creating a table after pivot (`SELECT * INTO final_results FROM pivot_query`) completes and use this table for subsequent analyses/reports. Run pivot only as needed.

Comment: Yes, I definitely did that.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I had some issues with getting all the desired results because there's a character limit on NResponses field (255). So all of the results were not captured when running the pivot query. I am trying to change the data type for NResponses to Longtext but can't seem to get it right. Any ideas?

Comment: Try breaking up query by companyID or by questions using `WHERE` in pivot query or `WHERE` on source table, *Surveys* in dynamic table build. Now, I am wondering with such a voluminous size of data, why do you need such a wide format and comma-separated values in one column?

Comment: -Good question - basically these are 200-question surveys that we ask people to complete.  The way that each question is answered tally's up to a score.  For any response that is a "N" it negatively affect that score. The comma-separated values are needed to quickly identify what impacted that score by question number.  Some may have answered "N" to all questions and that would consist of ~1100 characters after we aggregate them. So if I go with your advice I would probably need to break down the source query at least 4 times to ensure it's all aggregated correctly.  Does that help?.

Comment: Still think you should work out of long format (not comma-separated values in one column) which is scalable, readable, and more efficient (no row limit). Try asking a new question with more details of your final analysis needs. Wide formats rarely helps in analysis.

Answer (score 0):

hi, strOut  is a string, it must be an array.

try with something like this (unstested)

```
Dim strOut(10) ' array with 10 positions
Dim xAs Integer = 1 'var to array position
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        With rs
            For Each fld In .Fields
                If fld.Value = "N" Then
                    strOut(x) = strOut(x) & fld.Name & strSeperator
                    x=x+1
                End If

            Next fld
            rs.MoveNext
        End With
    Loop
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your input with this, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make it work.  @Parfait was able to get me where I needed, just wanted to express appreciation for your input.